# Script on esp8266 using nodeMCU constantly runs

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I am using lualoader and I loaded the following script from [webserver example](http://nodemcu.com/index_en.html)

```
-- a simple http server
srv = net.createServer(net.TCP)
srv:listen(80, function(conn)
    conn:on("receive", function(sck, payload)
        print(payload)
        sck:send("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<h1> Hello, NodeMCU.</h1>")
    end)
    conn:on("sent", function(sck) sck:close() end)
end)
```

I saved it in a file and loaded it to lualoader and then did `dofile`. Whenever I load send an HTTP request to the esp8266 it loads the webpage. This is even after running other scripts. From reading the script it looks like it can only handle one HTTP request. Why does it keep handling new http requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From reading the script it looks like it can only handle one HTTP request.

Not sure what you mean by that. Do you maybe refer to http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/http/? That is about sending *out* requests, only 1 concurrent requests.

> Why does it keep handling new http requests?

The server keeps listening until you close it.

```
srv:close()
```

Comment: The first question is the same as the second question. That answers it. Thanks!